# How to create a new matrix using MIN and MAX from original array

Tags: python

I have a matrix named A, and I want to create a new matrix named B, where each element value is generated by this formula:

`B[i][j] = (A[i][j] - MIN) / (MAX - MIN)`, where

- `i` is the line index
- `j` is the column index.
- `MIN` is the minimum from `A`
- `MAX` is the value with highest value from `A`.

I tried a for loop but I want to **increase efficiency**, I want to use numpy function but I don't know which function I have to use and how to use this function, with my problem.

Comment: What is `i` and `j`

Comment: I edited now, it's about a matrix. i and j are the indexes for line / column of matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the `MIN`&`MAX` are standing for

1. the `MIN`&`MAX` value of the column/row from `A`, or
2. the `MIN`&`MAX` value of the entire matrix(`A`).

Plz leave a comment if I'm misunderstanding and here's the solution for second meaning of `MIN`&`MAX`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)))
MAX, MIN = A.max(), A.min()
B = np.matrix((A - MIN)/(MAX - MIN))
print(A)
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
[[0.         0.09090909 0.18181818 0.27272727]
 [0.36363636 0.45454545 0.54545455 0.63636364]
 [0.72727273 0.81818182 0.90909091 1.        ]]
```

Comment: Also, you could use `sklearn` library. This process on matrix is called [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn-preprocessing-minmaxscaler).